# How to make laser made by line renderer get a effect of continuous damage?

Tags: unity, c#

I tried to implement a way of laser attacking. the character will shoot a laser implemented by the line renderer. the laser can detect an enemy using raycast hit, but it seems can only damage once. how to achieve continuous damage?
The code to shoot laser

```
if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        lr.enabled = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < segmentCount; i++)
        {

            currentPosition = transform.position;
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                currentPosition += resultVectors[j] * blockLength;
            }

            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(currentPosition, resultVectors[i], out hit, blockLength))
            {
                hitPosition = currentPosition + resultVectors[i] * hit.distance;
                hitPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(hitPosition, transform.position, moveHitToSource);
                if (hitEffect)
                {
                    hitEffect.transform.position = hitPosition;
                }

                dist = Vector3.Distance(hitPosition, transform.position);

                if (hit.transform.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
                {
                    hit.transform.GetComponent<enemyHealth>().takeDamage(20);
                }


                break;
            }
        }
        globalProgress = 0f;
    }
```

Comment: Do you use the line renderer to render one straight line, or does it have more than two points?

Comment: If it is a straight line, a simple raycast might work to detect hits

Comment: Unity provides a whole host of contact detection tools, including trigger colliders, ray/circle/spherecasts, or physics overlap queries. What have you tried based on your research so far, or tutorials you've followed? [Just typing "Unity LineRenderer laser" into a search engine turns up several existing guides about implementing this kind of feature](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=unity+linerenderer+laser&ia=web) — did you get stuck somewhere in particular when trying to use these existing resources?

Comment: yeah, raycast can detect enemies. but if it is a laser, the damage should be continuous, all I know for now is to use collision stay, but the way we detect the enemy is not using collider here.

Comment: `but the way we detect the enemy is not using collider here` you might want to post the code part how you detect the enemy so we can help you with what you have already

Comment: If you are calling this in Update or FixedUpdate, you get the effect of continuous damage by detecting the same raycast hit frame after frame. If that's not what you observe, you should show the complete code you're using, not just this cropped excerpt.

Comment: I am calling this in Update.  you are right, I got it now, it turns out that it damages every frame. So is there any way to slow it down?

Comment: I figured it out, just use a timer to countdown to make it call the function every second. Thank you all for your patient and careful explanation.

Comment: Be sure to post your solution as an Answer below.

Answer (score -1):

```
 if (hit.transform.gameObject.tag == "Enemy" && timer<0)
                {
                    hit.transform.GetComponent<enemyHealth>().takeDamage(20);
                    timer = 1.5f;
                }
```

Add these codes to control the frequency of damage.

Comment: You forgot the code which reduces the variable `timer` again.

Comment: This answer also fails to adjust for Time.deltaTime.